# Android, click on checkbox in my list doesn't affect onListItemClick() method?

Tags: android, list, checkbox, listener

In my application, I have a list. This list includes some texts and a checkbox. In Xml definition of list, If I put `android:focusable="true"` then I can click it and change it's status from checked to not checked and vice versa. But I can't change its status when I click on its row.

If I put `android:focusable="false"` the story will exchange. If I choose row, I can change the status of checkbox while if I click on it, nothing will change. **I need regardless of clicking on row or checkbox, status of chackbox changes.** If i click on checkbox it's status will change but my list doesn't aware of this changes therefore, onListItemClick() not execute.

I tried to add another element `android:enabled="false"`. But UI is not user friendly. Also, when I click on checkbox its status is not changed.

What is your suggestion?

This is xml code of list:

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:padding="6dip" >

            <CheckBox 
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
                android:focusable="false" />

.
.
.
```

and in code: Flag and planId are String Array.

```
private String[] flag = new String[50];
private String[] planId = new String[50];

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.i("List Clicked:", "******");

        //Toggle CheckBox from not selected to selected and vice versa.
        if(flag[position] == "true")
            flag[position] = "false";
        else
            flag[position] = "true";

        //Keep this CheckBox selected and clear the rest.
        for(int i=0; i<position; i++)
            flag[i] = "false";
        for(int i=position+1; i<flag.length; i++)
            flag[i] = "false";

        //If checkBox is selected show dialog if cleared don't show
        if(flag[position] == "true")
            //alertDialog.show();
            dialog.show();

        //Extracting Plan Id
        subscriptionPlanId = planId[position];
    }
```

screen capture:

[image]

=======>
**Update**:

```
//*********************
    //  RowModel Class
    //*********************
    private class RowModel{
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    //*********************
    //  ListAdapter Class
    //*********************
    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public ListAdapter(Context c) {
            super(c, R.layout.infindo_listformat, list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            RowModel holder;
            View row = convertView;

            if(row == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infindo_listformat, parent, false);

                holder = new RowModel();
                holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder.description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.description); 
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

                row.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (RowModel) row.getTag(); 
            }

            holder.title.setText(titels[position]);
            holder.description.setText(descriptions[position]);
            String s = flag[position];
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
            else
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);

            return(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your crash log (logcat using DDMS perspective) also

Comment: There is no crash, dear Adil.

Comment: Oh! but you had crash bit in your question title..!! That's why.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry, I changed the topic because I solve the problem of crashing. I have just above issue.

Comment: could you post your `getView()` and what is `flag[]` in your code.

Comment: I updated above post. Thanks.

Comment: That's not how you compare strings. Use `equals`. (If i had a nickel for everytime i corrected this on SO...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I answer my question here because above is so messy and confusable. For future reference I put my answer here.

**Question**: When I click on checkbox in a list, its status will change but onListItemClick() method, doesn't aware of this change and therefore this method will not run.

**Answer**: In XML elemnts of checkbox, just set clickable of this item to false. :) the problem is solved. In my case the XML is:

```
<Check
android:id="@+id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false" />
```

Now, regardless of clicking on row or checkbox, onListItemClick() method will call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code to check or uncheck the checkbox by using `(checkbox.setChecked())` in `onListItemClick` method

your code for onListItemClick will be some thing like following

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < rl.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if ((rl.getChildAt(i)) instanceof CheckBox) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rl.getChildAt(i);
                boolean check = cb.isChecked();
                cb.setChecked(!check);
                break;
            }
        }
//      System.out.println(rl.getChildCount() + "...v..." + rl + "...." + id);
        // boolean check = cb.isChecked();
        // cb.setChecked(!check);
    }
```

### Complete Example

**MyListVIew.java**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyListView extends ListActivity {

    AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete;

    String item[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // getIntent().getParcelableExtra("obj");
        // b.putSerializable("mybean", bean);
        // i.putExtra("obj", b);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("obj");
        MyBean dData = (MyBean) b.getSerializable("mybean");
        String[][] str = dData.get2DArray();
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context _context;
        TextView tv;

        public MyAdapter(Context context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return item.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return item[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
            }
            tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textview);

            // Set the Day GridCell
            tv.setText(item[position]);

            return row;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < rl.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if ((rl.getChildAt(i)) instanceof CheckBox) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rl.getChildAt(i);
                boolean check = cb.isChecked();
                cb.setChecked(!check);
                break;
            }
        }
//      System.out.println(rl.getChildCount() + "...v..." + rl + "...." + id);
        // boolean check = cb.isChecked();
        // cb.setChecked(!check);
    }

}
```

**mylist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```